# SwiftUI - What's the most efficient way to update the properties of a Struct that has too many properties?

Tags: swiftui

Let's say I have the following model:

## Model

```
struct Product {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var price: Double
    var property1: String
    var property2: String
    var property3: String
    var property4: String
    var property5: String
    
}
```

And this is my view:

## View

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var productId = 0
    @State var productName = ""
    @State var productPrice = 0.0
    @State var productProperty1 = ""
    @State var productProperty2 = ""
    @State var productProperty3 = ""
    @State var productProperty4 = ""
    @State var productProperty5 = ""
    
    var product = Product(id: 1, name: "Flour", price: 2.99, property1: "1", property2: "2", property3: "3", property4: "4", property5: "5")
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Product ID: \(productId)")
            Text("Product Name: \(productName)")
            Text("Product Price: \(productPrice)")
        }
            .onAppear {
                productId = product.id
                productName = product.name
                productPrice = product.price
                productProperty1 = product.property1
                productProperty2 = product.property2
                productProperty3 = product.property3
                productProperty4 = product.property4
                productProperty5 = product.property5
            }
    }
}
```

This works, but it feels too "clunky" and repetitive. Is there a better way to write this code?

I'm more concerned about the `.onAppear` part. I feel like there is a much better way to load my struct's properties without having to list them one by one like this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yep, try adding your own ‘init’. Just make sure to use ‘initialValue’ to set the States.

Comment: Hi @aheze! The .onAppear is just an example. In my actual code I get the properties from an API and I want to update them in a View where the user can modify the product. I was trying to ilustrate my problem in the simplest way I could. Does that make sense?

Comment: Maybe just add ‘@State’ in front of your ‘var product’. Then just reference each of its properties in your views (for example ‘Text("Product Name: \(product.productName))’, and get rid of all the other States.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are creating the `@State`s so you can have a `Binding` to them.

What you can do is make `product` a `@State` variable, and then you can access the bindings through the `product` like:

```
product.name // String: regular name
$product.name // Binding<String>: binding to name
```

New code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var product = Product(
        id: 1,
        name: "Flour",
        price: 2.99,
        property1: "1",
        property2: "2",
        property3: "3",
        property4: "4",
        property5: "5"
    )

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Product ID: \(product.id)")
            Text("Product Name: \(product.name)")
            Text("Product Price: \(product.price)")

            TextField("Product name field", text: $product.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
struct Product {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var price: Double
    var property1: String
    var property2: String
    var property3: String
    var property4: String
    var property5: String 
}
 
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var product = Product(id: 1, name: "Flour", price: 2.99, property1: "1", property2: "2", property3: "3", property4: "4", property5: "5")
    
    var body: some View {

            Text("Product ID: \(product.id)")
            Text("Product Name: \(product.name)")
            Text("Product Price: \(product.price)")

    }
    
}
```